# What benefit does specifying a type for Collection<T> have?

Tags: java, kotlin, collections

The [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface requires a type ...

What benefit does `Collection<Int>` have over `Collection<Any>` (which is the same but allows for all types) ?

Comment: Please choose a language. Are you asking about Java or Kotlin?

Comment: (1) No need to explicitly cast items you retrieve from collection. (2) Compiler safety checks that only objects of the right type are added to the collection.

Comment: Can you elaborate on point 1? @MichaelButscher what exactly does casting mean in this context?

Comment: @Andreas Writing in Kotlin using a Java library (Collections)

Comment: This is the same as asking "what be benefits do generics have?". Is that what you're asking? If so, the internet is absolutely packed with answers to this question. But short story - how would you write `myList.get(i)` under you suggested alternative?

Answer (score 2):

`Collection<T>` - is a **generic** interface. Generic classes enable programmers to specify, with a single class or interface declaration, a set of related types.
Java 1.5 and Kotlin came with Generics and all collection interfaces and implementations use it heavily.

Generics allow us to provide the type of `Object` that a collection can contain, so if you try to add any element of other type it throws **compile time error**. Generics provide compile-time type safety that allows programmers to catch invalid types at compile time.
It means if you write like this the compiler will give an error:

```
val collection: MutableCollection<Int> = mutableListOf()
collection.add("some string") // compile time error saying "Type mismatch"
```

This avoids `ClassCastException` at Runtime because you will get the error at compilation (**"Type mismatch"**). Also Generics make code clean since **we don’t need to use casting and `instanceof` operator in Java or `as` operator in Kotlin**. That means if we specify explicit type, for example  `MutableCollection<String>` we don't need to cast it when we get it from the Collection:

```
val collection: MutableCollection<String> = mutableListOf()
collection.add("Some string")

val data: String = collection.elementAt(0) // don't need to cast to String
```

If we use `MutableCollection<Any>`, we need explicitly cast data:

```
val collection: MutableCollection<Any> = mutableListOf()
collection.add("Some string")

val data: String? = collection.elementAt(0) as? String // explicitly casting using `as` operator
```

It also adds up to runtime benefit because the bytecode instructions that do type checking are not generated.